# Validate form element which is not required

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I got something like this here:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="apMin" placeholder="0">
</div>
<div class="col-md-2 text-center">-</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="apMax" placeholder="0" ng-required="apMin < apMax">
</div>
```

What I need now is to make sure, that apMin is not higher than apMax. I tried something like:

```
ng-required="apMin < apMax"
```

This field doesn't need to be required but more important is the logic to work.
Someone knows how to realize it?

Answer (score 1):

Could you use the min and max attributes on the input?

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="apMin" placeholder="0" max="{{apMax-1}}"/>
```

and

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="apMax" placeholder="0" min="{{apMin+1}}"/>
```

Comment: Yes that one worked very well. I am not sure, if this is the best solution but at least it is a solution i can use for now. thx very much

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting that logic in a controller using a $watch on both variables.

```
 $scope.$watch("apMin", function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal > $scope.apMax) {
      alert("-Min cannot be greating then max");
      $scope.apMin = $scope.apMax - 1;
    }
  });

  $scope.$watch("apMax", function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (newVal < $scope.apMin) {
      alert("+Min cannot be greating then max");
      $scope.apMax = $scope.apMin + 1;
    }
  });
```

See this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/j0BuJzKno5DRb5YkorRR?p=preview)

Or you can try just attaching a ng-blur on the apMax text box and check to make sure apMax isn't less than apMin.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

checkout this link for [min/max directives](http://jsfiddle.net/g/s5gKC/)

you can use them like:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="value1" ng-min="minValue" name="value1"/>
<input type="number" ng-model="value2" ng-max="maxValue" name="value2"/>
```